# object reference not set to an instance of object

Tags: vb.net

I have been getting an error in **VB .Net**

> object reference not set to an instance of object.

Can you tell me what are the causes of this error ?

Comment: it would be good if you can post your code file that generates this error

Comment: post the code so we're not shooting in the dark; or at least describe what's going on!

Comment: please add your code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sef,
If the problem is with Database return results, I presume it is in this scenario:

```
   dsData = getSQLData(conn,sql, blah,blah....)
   dt = dsData.Tables(0)  'Perhaps the obj ref not set is occurring here
```

To fix that:

```
  dsData = getSQLData(conn,sql, blah,blah....)
   If dsData.Tables.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
   dt = dsData.Tables(0)  'Perhaps the obj ref not set is occurring here
```

**edit**: added code formatting tags ...

Comment: You may want to use the code formatting tags for this answer.

Answer (score 10):

The object has not been initialized before use.

At the top of your code file type:

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On
```

Comment: Option Explicit, for those who may not know, forces declaration of variables.  This means that if you fat-finger a variable name, the compiler will not assume you intended to create another variable, and it will complain.  Option Strict means that if you want the type of a variable translated, then you'll do it manually.

Answer (score 7):

Let's deconstruct the error message.

"object reference" means a variable you used in your code which referenced an object.  The object variable could have been declared by you the or it you might just be using a variable declared inside another object.

"instance of object"  Means that the object is blank (or in VB speak, "**Nothing**").  When you are dealing with object variables, you have to create an **instance** of that object before referencing it.

"not set to an " means that you tried to access an object, but there was nothing inside of it for the computer to access.

If you create a variable like

```
Dim aPerson as PersonClass
```

All you have done was tell the compiler that aPerson will represent a person, but not ***what*** person.

You can create a blank copy of the object by using the "New" keyword.  For example

```
Dim aPerson as New PersonClass
```

If you want to be able to test to see if the object is "nothing" by

```
If aPerson Is Nothing Then
    aPerson = New PersonClass
End If
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

In general, under the .NET runtime, such a thing happens whenever a variable that's unassigned or assigned the value `Nothing` (in VB.Net, `null` in C#) is dereferenced.

`Option Strict On` and `Option Explicit On` will help detect instances where this may occur, but it's possible to get a null/Nothing from another function call:

```
Dim someString As String = someFunctionReturningString();
If ( someString Is Nothing ) Then
   Sysm.Console.WriteLine(someString.Length); // will throw the NullReferenceException
End If
```

and the [NullReferenceException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullreferenceexception.aspx#Mtps_DropDownFilterText) is the source of the "object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Answer (score 2):

And if you think it's occuring when no data is returned from a database query then maybe you should test the result before doing an operation on it?

```
Dim result As String = SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()   'just for scope'
If result Is Nothing OrElse IsDBNull(result) Then
    'no result!'
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put a logging mechanism in your application so you can isolate the cause of the error.  An Exception object has the StackTrace property which is a string that describes the contents of the call stack, with the most recent method call appearing first. By looking at it, you'll have more details on what might be causing the exception.

Answer (score 1):

When working with databases, you can get this error when you try to get a value form a field or row which doesn't exist. i.e. if you're using datasets and you use:

```
Dim objDt as DataTable = objDs.Tables("tablename")
```

you get the object "reference not set to an instance of object" if tablename doesn't exists in the Dataset. The same for rows or fields in the datasets.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Error is explaining itself. Since You haven't provided any code sample, we can only say somewhere in your code, you are using a Null object for some task. I got same Error for below code sample.

```
Dim cmd As IDbCommand
cmd.Parameters.Clear()
```

As You can see I am going to Clear a Null Object. For that, I'm getting Error

> "object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Check your code for such code in your code. Since you haven't given code example we can't highlight the code :)

Answer (score 0):

In case you have a class property , and multiple constructors, you must initialize the property in all constructors.