# What does Object reference not set to an instance of an object.mean

Tags: xml, vb.net

We are trying to read information from a separate XML document.

This is the code we have:

```
'load the XMLTest document containing cars.
    Dim xml As XDocument = XDocument.Load("CreditApp.xml")


    Dim SSN As String = txtSSN.Text
    'get all car makes that are red.
    Dim query = From xe In xml.Descendants("SSN")
         Where xe.Element("SSN").Value = SSN
                Select New With {
                    .FName = xe.Element("FName").Value 'Error in code is here
                }

    'loop through query result output results.
    For Each element In query.ToArray
        MessageBox.Show(element.FName)
    Next
```

We are getting the error:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

We are not sure what it is refering too.

Comment: It means you are getting a "NULL".

Comment: We are trying to match the SSN value we enter to the same value in the XML document. Then populate the other tags based on that set of data. How do we achieve this.

Comment: What line number of your code does the error message point to?  You are attempting to access a property of a `null` value.  For example, maybe `xe.Element("FName")` doesn't match any result, so when you say `.Value` it gives the exception.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in the debugger?  I'd ensure your query actually has a result, and check `txtSSN.Text` as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [object reference not set to an instance of object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/131053/object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-object)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you seed that message it means that you tried to access a member of a variable that currently has the value of `Nothing`.

```
Dim obj As Object = Nothing
Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString()) ' Null ref on obj access
```

The value `Nothing` in VB.Net (similar to C# `null`) means the object has no value.  Attempting to access a member on it is accessing a member on nothing.  The runtime can't satisfy this request and hence throws an exception to let you know about the problem.

In this particular sample it looks like the most likely cause of the error is the following line

```
FName = xe.Element("FName").Value
```

This code doesn't do anything to validate that `xe.Element("FName")` doesn't return `Nothing` and hence can lead to an exception when accessing the member `Value`.  To fix this you need to guard against this possibility.  The easiest way is to use a helper method

```
Public Function GetFNameValueOrEmpty(ByVal elem As XElement) As String
  Dim child = elem.Element("FName")
  If child Is Nothing Then
    Return String.Empty
  Else
    Return child.Value
  End If
End Function
```

With this helper you could rewrite the original query as such

```
Dim query = From xe In xml.Descendants("SSN")
         Where xe.Element("SSN").Value = SSN
                Select New With {
                    .FName = GetFNameValueOrEmpty(xe)
                }
```

Comment: When we implement the above code we get an error Option strict on requires all function, property, and operation declarations to have an 'as' clause

Comment: @user512915 my bad, added the `As String` to the `Function`

Comment: Add `As String` to the function header: `Public Function GetFNameValueOrEmpty(Dim elem As XElement) As String`

Comment: I am now getting two errors on this.  1. FName = GetFNameValueOrEmpty(xe) errors as 'Declaration Expected' on 'FName'.   2. Public Function GetFNameValueOrEmpty(Dim elem As XElement) As String errors as 'Specifiers only valid at the beginning of the declaration' on the 'Dim'.

Comment: @user512915 sorry, that line was meant to be the replacement for the equivalent line in your original sample.  It's not meant to stand on it's own like that

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure where you are referencing?

Comment: @user512915 i updated my answer to have the updated code sample

Comment: We are getting an error under the (Dim elem As XElement) As String

Comment: The error is underlining the Dim command and it reads Specifiers valid only at the begining of a statement

Comment: @user512915 again my bad, out of practice with VB.Net right now.  Fixed